# Getting error using py.test command in terminal with Windows 10

Tags: pytest

need some help ! - I am using the pytest Framwork for Selenium with Python. I ran the py.test commands from the commd prompt and it ran fine. Just when I tried

> py.test -m smoke -v -s
>   it started giving me the error below:
>   **The system cannot execute the specified program.**
>   Thereafter I am not able to run anything using py.test
>   It gives the same error.. I have searched on the web but no luck, I am stuck , has someone faced similar issue while working with Pytest? Please help !! Also please refer the attachment[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVXEP.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you use `python -m pytest` instead?

Comment: Run `where py.test` in the terminal, what does it output? Aside from that, `py.test` is deprecated; use `pytest` instead, or call as module: `python -m pytest`

Comment: Thanks ! I used pytest and this works ! I haven't tried python -m pytest , I will surely try it out . Appreciate your inputs !